# tensorflow2: how to save and load model weights to/from memory?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

How to save and load model weights to/from **memory** instead of disk in tensorflow2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can save and load a model into "memory/RAM". Although once you are done training, an instance of trained model will still stay in the memory if till the program terminates, which you can use for prediction etc. You can try Google Colab, where the instance can be used for longer time (approx. 12 hours). So once you train the model you can use it many times for prediction etc.

For saving and loading you have to give it some permanent memory space (ROM).